# TinyMCE failed to import styles

Tags: tinymce

I'm using tinymce 6.8.3 via the npm package and vite.
When importing `import 'tinymce/themes/silver';` like the [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/reference/themes/) say I get the errors shown in the picture.

[image]

Comment: have you created a `tinymce-config.js` in your project directory?

Comment: @Richie Nope, what's should be in there?

Comment: yes, I guess so, the link you provided says so

Comment: There's nothing written about a config file, as I see?

Comment: Try using this `import 'tinymce/themes/silver';` in the file, though this should be the first line
`import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce';`

Comment: @Richie That sadly didn't do the trick. I followed the exact example as shown here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/vite-es6-npm/ but the imports fail.

Comment: Have you tried to download from tinymce themselves? There is a free version, where all you need to do is register with them for a free API key and obviously install the files in the necessary folder?

Comment: No, I explicitly want to use it locally. Which must be possible with the npm package. Or just copying it into the structure.

Comment: You should be able to use it locally, otherwise there wouldn't be a download button
Here's a tutorial how to do it [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ll-aYoQCY5w]

Comment: A bit more to this. Does the folder `node_modules/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide` exist? You should find it in one level up from your project folder? If not, uninstall the npm tinymce with `npm uninstall tinymce` and re-install it with `npm install tinymce`, see if this works
You should link the `tinymce.min.js` like this `<script src="..\..\node_modules\tinymce\tinymce.min.js"></script>` to make tinymce work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same issue and this worked for me:

Follow instruction from https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/vite-es6-npm/ but change the below 2 lines:

```
/* content UI CSS is required */
import contentUiSkinCss from 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.js';

/* The default content CSS can be changed or replaced with appropriate CSS for the editor content. */
import contentCss from 'tinymce/skins/content/default/content.js';
```

Into:

```
/* content UI CSS is required */
import 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.js';
/* The default content CSS can be changed or replaced with appropriate CSS for the editor content. */
import 'tinymce/skins/content/default/content.js';
```

And make sure to add the 2 lines below to the tinymce initialization:

```
skin_url: 'default',
content_css: 'default',
```